# Crash caused by deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: uitableview

I have UISwitch and it's switch between 2 table view states. The problem is fast switching causing crash. I think it's because deleting row take some time (cuz animation) and if I added some cells and almost at the same time try to delete them then crash. What can I do? I really want animation, so [self.tableView reloadData] isn't solution.

```
- (void)switchChangedInIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EBOrderFormCell *cell = (EBOrderFormCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL on = cell.picker.on;
    if (indexPath.row == EBOrderFormTakeAway) {
        self.takeAway = on;
        [self takeAwayChanged];
    }
}

- (void)takeAwayChanged
{
    NSArray *notTakeAwayCells = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:EBOrderFormStreet inSection:0],
                                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:EBOrderFormHouseNumber inSection:0],
                                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:EBOrderFormFlatNumber inSection:0],
                                    nil];
    NSArray *takeAwayCells = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                              [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:EBOrderFormCafe inSection:0],
                              nil];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if (self.takeAway) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:takeAwayCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:notTakeAwayCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:notTakeAwayCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:takeAwayCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**Update:** Fixed it with code upon:

```
- (void)takeAwayChanged
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: "What can I do?" -- Make some visible effort to debug your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you'd disable user interaction during animation, but since you'd need a completion handler to know when to turn user interaction back on (table view batch updates don't provide this), you can try posting your batch updates to a block to give the table view a chance to stop churning:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        //...
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    });
```

I've solved crashes caused by overlapping batch updates by doing this. I have to say, though,  I attempted to reproduce your issue and couldn't. So there might be another issue.

If you still have trouble, consider building your table with [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It calculates and performs batch updates for you and is very robust. Specifically to your problem, try running the [Settings sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Settings/Settings/SettingsTableViewController.m). Toggling the "Sound" switch on and off rapidly hides and shows a row and doesn't crash.